# Python 3 and mpg321 formating

Tags: python, string, formatting, os.system

Im having some problems playing a random sound using mpg321.
First I make a list of all the sounds and also store the length in a variable I then create a random number between 0 and the length of that list. My problem is I do not know how to add that to the string inside os.system() for the file path.

```
sounds = os.listdir('./sounds/')  # creates list of all sound names
totalSounds = len(sounds)

sound_number = random.randint(0, len(sounds))
next_sound = str(sounds[sound_number])

soundPlaying = True
os.system('mpg321 ./sounds/%s') % next_sound
soundPlaying = False
```

I have tried using %s and putting the variable in after ./sounds/ but I get a syntax error saying os.system() only takes one argument.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution. I just made a string mpg321 ./sounds/ and another string for the file name and added those two strings together inside os.system()

Comment: please post your answer and mark your question as solved :)

Comment: I ended up using MrP01's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to do string formatting on the string, not on the function call

```
os.system('mpg321 ./sounds/%s'%next_sound)
```

By the way, I would use subprocess, which provides a much more handsome API than os.system! (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["mpg321", "./sounds/%s" % next_sound])
```